# Hive: How can i build a UDTF ?

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, hive

I made a own UDTF function from a tutorial and loaded the jar into hive. Now I want to create my own function to call the UDTF.

```
statement.executeUpdate("ADD JAR /home/hfu/myjar.jar;");
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION my_function AS 'com.effectivemeasure.hive.UDFT'");
```

I get an Exception when I run the the last CodeSnippet :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:296)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeUpdate(HiveStatement.java:406)
    at connectToHiveServer2.main(connectToHiveServer2.java:74)
```

What did I do wrong?

Here are the tutorials I used :

http://beekeeperdata.com/posts/hadoop/2015/07/26/Hive-UDTF-Tutorial.html  and 
http://www.ericlin.me/hive-user-defined-aggregation-function-udaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you're trying to use the UDF through JDBC.
Try the following things:

1. remove the ; at the end of each line
2. use *execute* instead of *executeUpdate*
3. make sure that the jar exists *where the hive server is*

Number 3 is worth a comment. When you execute a hive query from shell, your hive shell will package the UDTF jar together with other hive jars and submit it as an hadoop job. When using jdbc, this job is done by the hive server, so the JAR has to be stored in that path but *on the hive server*, which may not be the same machine you're using to run your program.